# JSON::ParserError in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Am trying to read data I just stored in the .json file, when running the script, am getting this error:

```
 /Users/topazjos/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/json-2.6.1/lib/json/common.rb:216:in `parse': 859: unexpected token at '[] (JSON::ParserError)
  from /Users/topazjos/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/json-2.6.1/lib/json/common.rb:216:in `parse'
  from /Users/topazjos/Documents/SQL & Ruby Projects/school-library/savedata.rb:48:in `fetch_people_datas'
```

it is showing that the error is coming from the`fecth_people_datas` method

```rb
class IOmanager
def save_people(persons)
    file = File.open('./people.json', 'a')
    person_data = persons.map do |person|
      if person.instance_of?(Teacher)
        { occupation: 'Teacher', name: person.name, age: person.age, specialization: person.specialization }
      else
        { occupation: 'Student', name: person.name, age: person.age, parent_permission: person.parent_permission }
      end
    end
    file.puts(JSON.generate(person_data))
  end

  def fetch_people_datas
    return [] unless File.exist?('./people.json')

    file = File.read('./people.json')
    array = []
    if file.empty?
      array
    else
      person_data = JSON.parse(file)
      person_data.map do |data|
        if data['occupation'] == 'Teacher'
          teacher = Teacher.new(data['age'], data['specialization'], data['name'])
          array.push(teacher)
        else
          student = Student.new(data['age'], data['classroom'], data['name'], data['parent_permission'])
          array.push(student)
        end
      end
    end
    array
  end
end
```

then am calling that method like this

```rb
class CreatePeople
  def initialize
    @iomanager = IOmanager.new
    @books = @iomanager.fetch_book_data
    @persons = @iomanager.fetch_people_datas
    @rentals = []
  end

  def create_student
    puts 'Create a new student'
    print 'Enter student age: '
    age = gets.chomp.to_i
    print 'Enter name: '
    name = gets.chomp
    print 'Has parent permission? [Y/N]: '
    parent_permission = gets.chomp.downcase
    case parent_permission
    when 'n'
      Student.new(age, 'classroom', name, parent_permission: false)
      @persons << student
      puts 'Student doesnt have parent permission, cant rent books'
    when 'y'
      student = Student.new(age, 'classroom', name, parent_permission: true)
      @persons << student
      puts 'Student created successfully'
    end
  end

  def create_teacher
    puts 'Create a new teacher'
    print 'Enter teacher age: '
    age = gets.chomp.to_i
    print 'Enter teacher name: '
    name = gets.chomp
    print 'Enter teacher specialization: '
    specialization = gets.chomp
    teacher = Teacher.new(age, specialization, name)
    @persons << teacher
    puts 'Teacher created successfully'
  end

  def json_runner
    @iomanager.save_book(@books)
    @iomanager.save_people(@persons)
    @iomanager.save_rental(@rentals)
  end
end
```

I have used the same way to read from the previous file fecth_book_data inside the same class and it has worked but I don't understand what went wrong here

Comment: Hold on. You said it's a `JSON::ParserError` but that it's occurring on `File.read(...)` (which has nothing to do with the Ruby json library). Which is it? Please provide a full stack trace, as text, not an image. As well as an example JSON file that produces this behavior. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks, Silvo, I have tried to update my question, would you please have a look back at it?

Comment: Check in http://json.parser.online.fr that the `./people.json` file that is valid.

Comment: Among other problems, you open a file in append mode but never close it. Just because *file* goes out of scope doesn't mean the handle gets properly closed, so don't do that.